# Django-backend with Aurelia-frontend. Defining models in each of them violating DRY-principle?

Tags: django, django-models, aurelia

In my recent project I'd like to try out an Aurelia-frontend with a Django-backend.
I did some projects with Django and want to use Django REST API for my backend.
I'm new to Aurelia and read the documentation several times.

Now I'm wondering if it would be good practice to explicitly define models (eg. User with nickname, email, mobile, address etc.) in the Aurelia-frontend because in Django I already defined my models in the models.py for the database.  Since I fetch/ the data via api to my Django application I could maybe omit it.
In the Aurelia "getting started"-section of the documentation they defined the ToDo-model in a separate file, but the data wasn't attached to a database. Doing this seems to me like doing it twice (in back- and frontend) and violates the DRY principle.

What would you think is good practice? Thanks for your recommendations!

Comment: You might want to look at a way to automate building models, this is likely to be tech specific on how you'd do this

Answer (score 2):

Defining classes on the client side has its advantages. First, you can map the response data into a class instance, and work with the data that way. Though, working with a JSON object isn’t tough.

Second, serializing a class into JSON is easy. Plus, some backend frameworks expect a very specifically formatted JSON object; sometimes a class is the only practical way of doing that.

Third, one thing you can do with a class that you cannot do with a JSON object (as far as I know) is add methods/functions. That extensibility alone can be worth the effort.

It certainly isn’t unusual to have classes defined on the back and front end. I have worked with Aurelia, and Angular, they both work nicely with them. I have done an Aurelia app without client side classes. What I really missed there was no Intellisense (a fourth advantage) in the IDE since nothing was exported/imported. BTW, I use VS Code.

DRY is nice. But, showing intent can go a long way, especially if someone else picks up the code when you are done with it. Classes can help there. Fifth advantage, helps to show intent.

Finally, I am sure there are many more advantages.

Conclusion: I would recommend using client side classes. You will not regret it.

Hope this helps!